# Abort ReadStream on client connection close

Tags: node.js, stream

I am trying to send a (huge) file with a limited amount of data passing every second (using <kbd>**[TooTallNate/node-throttle](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-throttle)**</kbd>):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Throttle = require('throttle');
var throttle = new Throttle(64);

throttle.on('data', function(data){
    console.log('send', data.length);
    res.write(data);
});

throttle.on('end', function() {
    console.log('error',arguments);
    res.end();
});

var stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(throttle);
```

If I cancel the download at the clients browser, the stream will just continue until it completly transferred.
I also tested the scenario above with <kbd>**[npm node-throttled-stream](https://github.com/tec27/node-throttled-stream)**</kbd>, same behavour.

**How to cancel the stream if the browser closed his request?**

---

### Edit:

I am able to obtain the connections `close` event by using

```
req.connection.on('close',function(){});
```

But the `stream` has neither a `destroy` nor an `end` or `stop` property which I could use to stop the `stream` from further reading.

I does provide the property `pause` <kbd>**[Doc](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause)**</kbd>, but I would rather stop node from reading the whole file than just stopping to recieve the contents (as described in the doc).

Comment: I have the same question.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @user949300 I've added an answer of my workaround, may the force be with you :)

Comment: In my situation, which is a little different (no browser involved, I just want to read part of a file) a `stream.destroy()` seems to stop the readable stream from continuing to emit events (other than a 'close').

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the following *dirty* workaround:

```
var aborted = false;

stream.on('data', function(chunk){
    if(aborted) return res.end();

    // stream contents
});

req.connection.on('close',function(){
    aborted = true;
    res.end();
});
```

As mentioned above, this isn't really a nice solution, but it works.
Any other solution would be highly appreciated!